# Updating the Source Code of an App Deployed Through Google Cloud

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have an app hosted on Google Cloud service, and the code for the app is also on GitHub. I've made changes to the code on GitHub, but now I need to know how to update Google Cloud to reflect what I changed. How do I do this?

I've searched the pages available to me through console.cloud.google.com and there's nowhere that I've found where I can even see the code is being held, let alone make changes to it.

Comment: There are several methods. One method is to create a GitHub action to deploy your app on changes to the repository. https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-appengine

Comment: You can also deploy from your machine (laptop/desktop) by running the command ```gcloud app deploy```. Your deployed code is stored in a bucket (staging bucket) and remain there (before being deleted) for a default time of 15 days (you can change this time period). For more explanation about this, check the 'background' section of this [blog article](https://nocommandline.com/blog/how-to-download-your-source-code-from-google-app-engine-standard-env/) from us

Answer (score 2):

Posting as community wiki as per comments:

As per @JohnHanley:

> There are several methods. One method is to create a GitHub action to deploy your app on changes to the repository. github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-appengine

As per @NoCommandLine:

> You can also deploy from your machine (laptop/desktop) by running the command `gcloud app deploy`. Your deployed code is stored in a bucket (staging bucket) and remain there (before being deleted) for a default time of 15 days (you can change this time period). For more explanation about this, check the 'background' section of this [blog article](https://nocommandline.com/blog/how-to-download-your-source-code-from-google-app-engine-standard-env/) from us